# Church Numerals in haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I am trying to print church numerals in haskell using the definions:

```
0 := λfx.x
1 := λfx.f x
```

Haskell code:

```
c0 = \f x -> x
c1 = \f x -> f x
```

When I enter it in the haskell console I get an error which says

```
    test> c1

    <interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (Show ((t -> t1) -> t -> t1))
      arising from a use of `print' at <interactive>:1:0-1
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show ((t -> t1) -> t -> t1))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I am not able to exactly figure out what error says.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

The problem here is that, by default, it's not possible to print values in Haskell. The default way to print things--used by the `print` function and by the GHCi REPL, among others--is the `show` function, defined by the type class `Show`.

The error you're getting, then, is informing you that you've evaluated an expression of a type that doesn't have an instance of `Show` defined. Modulo some verbiage, this is all the error message is saying:

```
No instance for (Show ((t -> t1) -> t -> t1))
```

The type `((t -> t1) -> t -> t1)` is what was inferred for the expression you evaluated. This is a valid type for the Church numeral 1, though the "correct" type for a Church numeral should actually be `(a -> a) -> a -> a`.

```
  arising from a use of `print' at <interactive>:1:0-1
```

It's implicitly using the `print` function to display the values. Normally this would tell you where in your program the error was found, but in this case it says `<interactive>:1:0-1` because the error was caused by an expression in the REPL.

```
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Show ((t -> t1) -> t -> t1))
```

This is just suggesting that you could fix the error by defining the instance it was expecting.

---

Now, you probably want to actually print your Church numerals, not just know why you can't. Unfortunately, this isn't as simple as adding the instance it asked for: If you write an instance for `(a -> a) -> a -> a`, Haskell interprets this as an instance for *any specific `a`*, whereas the correct interpretation of a Church numeral is a polymorphic function that works on any arbitrary `a`.

In other words, you want your `show` function to be something like this:

```
showChurch n = show $ n (+1) 0
```

If you really want to, you may implement the Show instance like this:

```
instance (Show a, Num a) => Show ((a -> a) -> a -> a) where
    show n = show $ n (+1) 0
```

and add `{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances#-}` to the first line of the file. Or you may implement something similar to convert them to a regular number

```
> churchToInt c1
1
> showChurch c1
"1"
```

etc.

Comment: thanks for the detailed dissection of the error message. 
It makes more sense to me now. I'm trying to get better in understanding the errors thrown out :)

Comment: @RBK: You're welcome. :] GHC's error messages are usually pretty straightforward and helpful once you know the basic structure/jargon used, but I'm not aware of any self-contained guide to learning that. I mostly figured it out on my own, with some help from people on IRC and whatnot.

Comment: I tried implementing this and got an error, "Illegal instance declaration for `Show ((a -> a) -> a -> a)` (All instance types must be of the form ... distinct type variables".  Being days new to Haskell I'm not sure how to amend this.  Was hoping to having a playground for the lambda calculus for the next few hours without having to learn all of Haskell first.  Help?

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Spoiler Alert, as mentioned in the comment

Or, you could have a type for Church numerals, something like this:

```
data Church x = Church ((x -> x) -> x -> x)

zero :: Church x
zero = Church (\f x -> x)

-- Hack to not clash with the standard succ
succ_ :: Church x -> Church x
succ_ (Church n) = Church (\f x -> (f (n f x)))

instance (Num x) => Show (Church x) where
  show (Church f) = show $ f (1 +) 0
```

Comment: Warning: If you were trying to figure out how to implement Church numerals on your own, don't read this answer! It gives it all away!

Comment: This is still less than ideal, unfortunately--it works fine for simple expressions, but in more complicated uses the type variable `x` can unify with things you didn't intend. What you *really* want is `data Church = Church (forall x. (x -> x) -> x -> x)`.

Comment: I was thinking on those lines, but decided against it since I don't understand Rank 2 types very well myself.

Comment: Thanks all. I need to do more reading on the topic of typeclasses. Will use SCombinator's solution as a reference and try to do it on my own.

Comment: If it helps, you can read `forall a. (...)` as the capital-lambda-abstractions of System F, i.e. we can define `succ` as something like `λn:(Λa. (a → a) → a → a). Λa. λf:(a → a). λx:a. f (n a f x))`. If you're more comfortable with λ-calculus than fancy type systems, that might be easier to understand.