# Using the y combinator in haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, combinators

I'm a beginner in haskell, and trying to implement the Church encoding for natural numbers, as explained in [this guide](http://archive.is/dumJ2).
I used a definition of y combinator from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5886279/165753), but not sure how to apply it.

I'd like to implement a simple function in lambda calculus which computues the sum of [1..n] as demonstrated [here](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf).

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Unsafe.Coerce

y :: (a -> a) -> a
y = \f -> (\x -> f (unsafeCoerce x x)) (\x -> f (unsafeCoerce x x))

true = (\x y -> x)
false = (\x y -> y)

newtype Chur = Chr (forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a))

zer :: Chur
zer = Chr (\x y -> y)

suc :: Chur -> Chur
suc (Chr cn) = Chr (\h -> cn h . h)

ci :: Chur -> Integer
ci (Chr cn) = cn (+ 1) 0

ic :: Integer -> Chur
ic 0 = zer
ic n = suc $ ic (n - 1)


-- church pair
type Chp = (Chur -> Chur -> Chur) -> Chur

pair :: Chur -> Chur -> Chp
pair (Chr x) (Chr y)  f = f (Chr x) (Chr y)

ch_fst :: Chp -> Chur
ch_fst p = p true

ch_snd :: Chp -> Chur
ch_snd p = p false

next_pair :: Chp -> Chp
next_pair = (\p x -> x (suc (p true)) (p true))

n_pair :: Chur -> Chp -> Chp
n_pair (Chr n) p = n next_pair p

p0 = pair zer zer
pre :: Chur -> Chur
pre (Chr cn) = ch_snd $ n_pair (Chr cn) p0

iszero :: Chur -> (a->a->a)
iszero (Chr cn) = cn (\h -> false) true

unchr :: Chur -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))
unchr (Chr cn) = cn

ch_sum (Chr cn) = (\r -> iszero (Chr cn) zer (cn suc (r (pre (Chr cn)))))
```

So far so good, but how do I apply `y` to `sum`?
e.g.

```
n3 = ic 3
y ch_sum n3
```

causes a type mismatch:

```
<interactive>:168:3:
     Couldn't match type ‘(Chur -> Chur) -> Chur’ with ‘Chur’
     Expected type: ((Chur -> Chur) -> Chur) -> (Chur -> Chur) -> Chur
     Actual type: Chur -> (Chur -> Chur) -> Chur
     In the first argument of ‘y’, namely ‘ch_sum’
     In the expression: y ch_sum n3

<interactive>:168:10:
   Couldn't match expected type ‘Chur -> Chur’ with actual type ‘Chur’
   In the second argument of ‘y’, namely ‘n3’
   In the expression: y ch_sum n3
```

[Y Combinator in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273413/y-combinator-in-haskell) provides the definition of y combinator, but doesn't explain how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Y Combinator in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273413/y-combinator-in-haskell)

Comment: @chepner Why is that a duplicate? This question (which I linked to), provides the definition of y combinator, but doesn't explain how to use it.

Comment: @dimid See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5888847/1126841) to the proposed duplicate. You can't type the Y combinator.

Comment: @chepner So, then *obviously* [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36827099/2747511) won't typecheck and work? :)

Comment: @chepner Yeah, I know you need to use certain tricks, such as `unsafeCoerce`, but that's **not** the issue. The issue is that question provides the definition of y combinator, but doesn't explain how to use it, which is why i"ve asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've introduced the function `add` (which obviously adds two Church numerals) to simplify the `ch_sum`'s definition:

```
add :: Chur -> Chur -> Chur
add (Chr cn1) (Chr cn2) = Chr (\h -> cn1 h . cn2 h)
```

To create a recursive function using a fixed-point combinator, you need to write it as it was an ordinary recursive function (in a language with recursion), but as a last step add the *explicit* "self" argument as the first function's argument (`r` in this case) and instead of a recursive call you just call "self" (`r`). So `ch_sum` can be written as

```
ch_sum :: (Chur -> Chur) -> Chur -> Chur
ch_sum = \r n -> iszero n zer $ add n (r $ pre n)
```

A couple tests in ghci:

```
λ> let n3 = ic 3
λ> ci (y ch_sum n3)
6
λ> let n10 = ic 10
λ> ci (y ch_sum n10)
55
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's a bit clearer (at least for me) to define addition using the successor: `ch_add (Chr cn1) (Chr cn2) = cn1 suc (Chr cn2)`

Comment: Yes, you're right. That would be a cleaner approach (from several points of view): once we defined `zer` and `suc` (and maybe some other "primitives", like Church pairs, ...) we shouldn't use anything except those for building other arithmetic functions. By the way, `add (Chr cn1) arg2 = cn1 suc arg2` is another way to write the addition function (not in principal, it just avoids unfolding/folding of the second argument).

Comment: Also, it's possible to implement Church numerals without the `RankNTypes` extension, but then you will have to use an implementation akin to the version in my answer, because otherwise it won't typecheck.

Comment: Interesting, do you mean an implementation like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6464164/165753

Comment: Yes, but higher-order ranks give you much more in expressiveness.